# Cannot Publish Shiny Apps to shinyapps.io on a Mac

Tags: shiny, rstudio, shinyapps

I have written this shiny app for my homework last year, but recently I want to make it public so that employers can see it. However, I cannot publish the app which works fine locally to shinyapps.io ...

I have followed every step of the suggestions like [shinyapps.io getting started](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html), or tried to publish it from Rstudio, but will always end up with the same error:

```
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 604401511 failed: Error building image: Error building rgeos (0.4-1). Build exited with non-zero status: 1
```

I did solve this by using a Windows PC instead of Mac, but I'm just curious what's the issue here? I did recall that some classmate mentioned that she cannot even run the two-file shiny app on Mac. I was using the single-filed format, so it was okey for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one more time: publishing on a Window PC was fine, but something wrong with Mac. I think it's the way these OS build images are different, which made it difficult to do so from a Mac. Hope this will help someone struggling as I did.